# Use a dimension only as a slicer

Tags: activepivot

Users often want to be able to filter on high cardinality dimensions such as ISIN or counterpartyID.

Is there a way to use such dimensions as slicers but block them for being used in rows / columns ?

Best regards,

Christophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with the MDX-based web client interface ActivePivot Live.

To do so, you need to extend the class `OlapEntityToWizardExpressionConverter` and rebind the interface `IOlapEntityToWizardExpressionConverter` to your custom class through GIN (GWT INjection). Easily doable (only one line of code):

```
bind(IOlapEntityToWizardExpressionConverter.class).to(MyCustomizedOlapEntityToWizardExpressionConverter.class);
```

Then in your class, simply override the `visit(final Hierarchy hierarchy)` method:

```
    ...

    if(section.equals(ROWS) || section.equals(COLUMNS)){
          if(hierarchy.getName().equals(ISIN) ||  hierarchy.getName().equals(counterpartyID))){
               //Do something here (display a message...)
               return;
          }
     }

     super.visit(hiearchy);             

    ...
```

Users won't be able to put the dimension on an axis anymore.